# How to avoid OverlyPermissiveMethod issue?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, findbugs

In SonarQube 6.4 with the findbug plugin 3.5 installed, I see this issue in every build job:

```
INFO: Findbugs output report: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.........../findbugs-result.xml
The following errors occurred during analysis:
  Exception analyzing ch.axonivy.fintech.acrevis.document.service.AcrevisDocumentService using detector com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Incompatible bcel version
      At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod.getBootstrapMethod(OverlyPermissiveMethod.java:379)
      At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod.sawOpcode(OverlyPermissiveMethod.java:167)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.DismantleBytecode.visit(DismantleBytecode.java:881)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.BetterVisitor.visitCode(BetterVisitor.java:218)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.visitCode(PreorderVisitor.java:240)
      At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod.visitCode(OverlyPermissiveMethod.java:114)
      At org.apache.bcel.classfile.Code.accept(Code.java:132)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.doVisitMethod(PreorderVisitor.java:312)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.visitclass.PreorderVisitor.visitJavaClass(PreorderVisitor.java:400)
      At org.apache.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.accept(JavaClass.java:213)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BytecodeScanningDetector.visitClassContext(BytecodeScanningDetector.java:38)
      At com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod.visitClassContext(OverlyPermissiveMethod.java:96)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.DetectorToDetector2Adapter.visitClass(DetectorToDetector2Adapter.java:76)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.analyzeApplication(FindBugs2.java:1089)
      At edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:283)
      At org.sonar.plugins.findbugs.FindbugsExecutor$FindbugsTask.call(FindbugsExecutor.java:216)
      At java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
      At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
      At java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
  Exception analyzing ch.axonivy.fintech.acrevis.dossieroverview.AcrevisUserRole using detector com.mebigfatguy.fbcontrib.detect.OverlyPermissiveMethod
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, please follow
https://github.com/mebigfatguy/fb-contrib/issues/205